# Message/SMS Invite used by Google Firebase Invites. Is it chargeable by Network operator?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I want to understand once an app is integrated with the Google Firebase and we send app invite using `SMS / Message`. Is it sent over operators network, I mean will it be charged to the invite sender by its network operator or it is sent via some google's server. And user/sender will not be charged anything.

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.

Comment: @New16 the question is specifically about Firebase Invites, not about Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Invites are sent over SMS or email. For invitations are sent via SMS, normal carrier usage rates apply.